# Do math with JSON data (from an API) in HTML page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I'm used to working in Bash and doing math with variables is pretty simple. I'm trying to do math with data retrieved from an API and store the answer as a new variable.

The code below shows the response from the server, but I'd like to do some math on the number (divide by 100000000 to be specific) and then show the result in HTML. How can I do that?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
$.get( "https://blockchain.info/q/totalbc", function(response) {
    $("#BTCUSD").text(response);
}, "json" );

</script>
<body>
<span id="BTCUSD"></span>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#BTCUSD").text(response/100000000);
```

Things are pretty simple in jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `parseInt()` to ensure that you are working with an int value, then divide that.

```
var newValue = parseInt( response ) / 100000000;
$("#BTCUSD").text(newValue);
```

Because Javascript is loosely typed, you could also just use:

```
var newValue =  response / 100000000;
```

Comment: add try catch to enhance the code on the parseInt part

Comment: How would that "enhance" the code? `parseInt` never throws an exception, it returns NaN if the value is not a number.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators) if you want to learn about arithmetic operators in JavaScript.

As doublesharp said, the best idea is to parse the string as an integer, and then perform the division, but you could also specify the order of magnitude in this way:

```
var newValue = parseInt(response, 10) / 1E8;
$("#BTCUSD").text(newValue);
```

Comment: It would be **good** to add the radix to `parseInt()`, I mean: `parseInt( response, 10 );` for decimal integers. Even if current browsers assume base 10, older ones transform it to base 8 if the string starts with `0`. Better safe than sorry...

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript there are two things that pretty much everything thing has. `toString` and `valueOf` functions attached to the objects. The `toString` function is called when, well..., the object needs to be a string. The `valueOf` function is called when, once again, the object needs to be a value.

So, JavaScript provides [functionality to the `+`](http://www.adequatelygood.com/Object-to-Primitive-Conversions-in-JavaScript.html) that when placed in front of an object it will call the `valueOf` function for you! Therein to make your `response` object a number simply place `+` in front of it then math away!

**WARNING!!** JavaScript does not really throw errors for *mathing* wrong. As in `0/0` instead JavaScript will return `NaN` which ironically is a number to JavaScript. So, the easiest way to check to see if you have a `NaN` just throw that sucker into `isNaN` function which returns a boolean value.

```
...
<script>

$.get( "https://blockchain.info/q/totalbc", function(response) {
    var VALUE = +response;
    // If not NaN, get mathy!
    if(!isNaN(VALUE))
    {
        VALUE /= 100000000;
    }
    else
    {
       VALUE = "Uh oh... Cannot Math with " + response;
    }
    $("#BTCUSD").text(VALUE);
}, "json" );

</script>
...
```

Comment: Please specify as to why you down voted. That way I do not make the same mistake again.